# I want to increase the score in mini tennis game

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I'm creating a basic 'mini tennis game'  I would like for the score to increase by one point each time the ball makes contact with the racket. I already have the score displayed on the screen at 0 but I don't know how to make it increase.  I would greatly appreciate any help you could give me.  Here is the code I have so far:

Game class

```
private int score = 0;

Ball ball = new Ball(this);
SecondBall ball2 = new SecondBall(this);
Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);

public Game() {
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            racquet.keyPressed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            racquet.keyReleased(e);

        }
    });
    setFocusable(true);
}

private void move() {
    ball.move();
    ball2.move();
    racquet.move();

}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    ball.paint(g2d);
    ball2.paint(g2d);
    racquet.paint(g2d);

    **//Show score on screen
    String s = Integer.toString(score);
    String sc = "Your score: ";
    g.drawString(sc, getWidth()-150, 50);
    g.drawString(s, getWidth()-50, 50);**
}

public void gameOver() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Suck!!", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.exit(ABORT);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

}

Ball Class

```
private static final int DIAMETER = 30;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int xa = 1;
int ya = 1;
private Game game;
private int score = 0;
private String yourScoreName;

public Ball(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public void move() {

    if (x + xa < 0) 
        xa = 1;
    if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER)
        xa = -1;
    if (y + ya < 0) 
        ya = 1;
    if (y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER)
        game.gameOver();
    if (collision()) {
        ya = -1;
        y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
    }


    x = x + xa;
    y = y + ya;
}

private boolean collision() {
    return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
}
```

}

Comment: increase the `score` variable and repaint the score on the game?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a collision method which returns true if the ball collides with your racquet. So you can easily increment your score:

```
if (collision()) {
    ya = -1;
    y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
    score++; //// like this
}
```

Just an advice, by copy pasting a tutorial you wont learn it. Start at the beggining.